Issue while installing selenium-wire
I wanted to use selenium-wire to intercept requests from Selenium to remote host. I tried to install it using PIP, it installed successfully without any issues, but when I went to import it on my project its giving me error as follows:
no module named 'blinker._saferef
I tried to dig in the issue, but found nothing. I can tell that it is due to the library itself is now discontinued. Can you help me with this issue?
I tried to find the root cause of the error expecting it to solve my issue, but couldn't find anything.

You seem to be facing issue which is not related to the library itself but the dependency of the library. Please uninstall the version of blinker._saferef, issue the command below:
pip uninstall selenium-wire 
pip uninstall blinker

once its uninstall use the blinker version which is less than 1.8.0, use following command:
pip install blinker==1.7.0

Finally install selenium-wire:
pip install selenium-wire

Try to use the library, it should work.

Thank you, it solved my issue. Very much appreciated!!

Consider accepting the answer if it solved your issue.
